# Setting image width according both container width and image's original width using CSS?

Tags: css

Is there any way to get the following effect using CSS?

- When container's width is less than image's original width, set image's width to 100% of container's width.
- When container's width is larger than image's original width, set image's width to it's original wdith.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Do you have some code to post with your question?

Comment: CSS3 does offer math, but this might be easier with jQuery.

Comment: I didn't get any solution. Just suprising that there's no way to achieve such a simple goal with CSS. I will check CSS3's math.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the following CSS code could achieve the goal. But according to CSS Standard, when the value of max-width is percentage, it is *"calculated with respect to the width of the generated box's containing block"*. According to my understanding, set max-width to 100% should take no effect, but it seems wrong.

```
img{
    width: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

The code is tested in Firefox 12 and IE 9. See http://jsfiddle.net/EnZEP/

Answer (score 2):

May be you can do like this:

for example:

```
img{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    max-width:400px;
}
```

check this http://jsfiddle.net/aqh2r/

Comment: Well, what about that there are images with different width? Is it possible to achieve the goal with only CSS?

Comment: Yes, the method works fine. But my means is that, if there are two image of 600 and 400 pix width, the rule will make they both showed with maximum width of 400, the 600px width image won't been shown lager than 400px width.